# Add borders into a textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

I need to reproduce this contact form.
[image: Contact form to reproduce]

It's already done, but i got some problems for the textarea.

Seems I need to put kinds of "hr" into the textarea, or... or I don't know.
Any help would be welcome.

Comment: "*It's already done*" - great, can we see? It would make it a lot easier for us to help you, if we could.

Comment: Sure. I've upload it here. [link](http://bartoman.fr/minimize/)

Comment: Could you possibly add the relevant code, the html and CSS, to your question? Otherwise, should you ever reorganise your site, this question becomes effectively meaningless for future users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `linear-gradient` where the `background-size` is equal to the `line-height` defined for the `textarea`, e.g.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LELJzy

```
textarea {
   font-size: 16px;
   width: 80%;
   height: 200px;
   color: #fff;
   line-height: 1.7em;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000 98%, #fff 98%);
   background-size: 1.7em 1.7em;
}
```

Whit this approach you don't need an extra request for a background image and the lines may vary their position depending on the user `font-size` (try increasing/decerasing the zoom factor).

The tickness of the lines can be adjusted defining a different color-stop value.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a background-image for `1px by 16px` which would be similar to a `|` and use repeat for the background:

```
textarea{
   background: url(line.jpg) repeat;
}
```

Comment: Are there any others solutions than images ?
Cause it need to be responsive, and I'm a bit afraid about image

Comment: It's just 1px width image, why to fear to use it?

Comment: Cause i'm not so good :) Btw, thanx for the answer, gonna test it.